# Zabbix Agent Install On Amazon Linux through Chef - Agent Starting and Stopping Got signal [signal:15(SIGTERM)reason:0]. Exiting

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, zabbix

```
    Starting Zabbix Agent [ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX]. Zabbix 3.2.3 (revision 64610).
    **** Enabled features ****
    IPv6 support: NO
    TLS support: NO
    **************************
    using configuration file: /usr/local/etc/zabbix_agentd.conf
    agent #0 started [main process]
    agent #4 started [listener #3]
    agent #1 started [collector]
    agent #3 started [listener #2]
    agent #2 started [listener #1]
    Got signal [signal:15(SIGTERM),sender_pid:10271,sender_uid:0,reason:0]. Exiting …
    Got signal [signal:15(SIGTERM),sender_pid:10271,sender_uid:0,reason:0]. Exiting …
    Got signal [signal:15(SIGTERM),sender_pid:10271,sender_uid:0,reason:0]. Exiting …
    One child process died (PID:9908,exitcode/signal:1). Exiting …
    Got signal [signal:15(SIGTERM),sender_pid:10271,sender_uid:0,reason:0]. Exiting …
    Zabbix Agent stopped. Zabbix 3.2.3 (revision 64610).


**Detailed Zabbix log with Log Level 4:-** 


 Starting Zabbix Agent [ip-xxx.xx.xx.xx]. Zabbix 3.2.3                                                                                                              (revision 64610).
**** Enabled features ****
IPv6 support:           NO
TLS support:            NO
**************************
using configuration file: /usr/local/etc/zabbix_agent                                                                                                             d.conf
In zbx_load_modules()
End of zbx_load_modules():SUCCEED
In init_collector_data()
In zbx_dshm_create() proj_id:112 size:0
End of zbx_dshm_create():SUCCEED shmid:-1
End of init_collector_data()
agent #0 started [main process]
agent #1 started [collector]
agent #3 started [listener #2]
__zbx_zbx_setproctitle() title:'listener #2 [waiting                                                                                                              for connection]'
agent #2 started [listener #1]
  In init_cpu_collector()
  __zbx_zbx_setproctitle() title:'listener #1 [waiting                                                                                                              for connection]'
  End of init_cpu_collector():SUCCEED
  __zbx_zbx_setproctitle() title:'collector [processing                                                                                                              data]'
  In update_cpustats()
  End of update_cpustats()
  __zbx_zbx_setproctitle() title:'collector [idle 1 sec                                                                                                             ]'
  agent #4 started [listener #3]
  __zbx_zbx_setproctitle() title:'listener #3 [waiting                                                                                                              for connection]'
  __zbx_zbx_setproctitle() title:'collector [processing                                                                                                              data]'
  In update_cpustats()
  End of update_cpustats()
  __zbx_zbx_setproctitle() title:'collector [idle 1 sec                                                                                                             ]'
  __zbx_zbx_setproctitle() title:'collector [processing                                                                                                              data]'

  In update_cpustats()
  End of update_cpustats()
  __zbx_zbx_setproctitle() title:'collector [idle 1 sec                                                                                                             ]'
  __zbx_zbx_setproctitle() title:'collector [processing                                                                                                              data]'
  In update_cpustats()
  End of update_cpustats()
  __zbx_zbx_setproctitle() title:'collector [idle 1 sec                                                                                                             ]'
  Got signal [signal:15(SIGTERM),sender_pid:10231,sende                                                                                                             r_uid:0,reason:0]. Exiting ...
  zbx_on_exit() called
  Got signal [signal:15(SIGTERM),sender_pid:10231,sende                                                                                                             r_uid:0,reason:0]. Exiting ...
  Got signal [signal:15(SIGTERM),sender_pid:10231,sende                                                                                                             r_uid:0,reason:0]. Exiting ...
  Got signal [signal:15(SIGTERM),sender_pid:10231,sende                                                                                                             r_uid:0,reason:0]. Exiting ...
  Got signal [signal:15(SIGTERM),sender_pid:10231,sende                                                                                                             r_uid:0,reason:0]. Exiting ...
  In zbx_dshm_destroy() shmid:-1
  End of zbx_dshm_destroy():SUCCEED
  In zbx_unload_modules()
  End of zbx_unload_modules()
  Zabbix Agent stopped. Zabbix 3.2.3 (revision 64610).
```

Chef Logs

```
 Synchronizing Cookbooks:
   - s3_file (2.5.1)
   - zabbix (0.1.1)
 Installing Cookbook Gems:
 Compiling Cookbooks...
 Converging 7 resources
 Recipe: zabbix::aml
   * yum_package[gcc] action install (up to date)
   * remote_file[/home/zabbix-3.2.3.tar.gz] action create
     - create new file /home/zabbix-3.2.3.tar.gz
     - update content in file /home/zabbix-3.2.3.tar.gz from none to e6dba7
     (file sizes exceed 10000000 bytes, diff output suppressed)
     - change mode from '' to '0755'
     - change owner from '' to 'root'
     - change group from '' to 'root'
   * bash[agent-install] action run
     - execute "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20170125-2651-klp1so"
   * directory[/etc/zabbix] action create
     - create new directory /etc/zabbix
     - change mode from '' to '0755'
     - change owner from '' to 'zabbix'
     - change group from '' to 'zabbix'
   * template[/usr/local/etc/zabbix_agentd.conf] action create
     - update content in file /usr/local/etc/zabbix_agentd.conf from 2fefc4 to 10bb5e
     --- /usr/local/etc/zabbix_agentd.conf    2017-01-25 00:41:40.469538172 +0000
     +++ /usr/local/etc/.chef-zabbix_agentd20170125-2651-1p0i3vw.conf 2017-01-25 00:41:50.917553880 +0000
     @@ -1,77 +1,78 @@
     +
      # This is a configuration file for Zabbix agent daemon (Unix)
      # To get more information about Zabbix, visit http://www.zabbix.com


      ### Option: PidFile
     -#       Name of PID file.
     +#       Name of PID file.
      #
      # Mandatory: no
      # Default:
     -# PidFile=/tmp/zabbix_agentd.pid
     +PidFile=/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.pid

      ### Option: LogType
     -#       Specifies where log messages are written to:
     -#               system  - syslog
     -#               file    - file specified with LogFile parameter
     -#               console - standard output
     +#       Specifies where log messages are written to:
     +#               system  - syslog
     +#               file    - file specified with LogFile parameter
     +#               console - standard output
      #
      # Mandatory: no
      # Default:
      # LogType=file

      ### Option: LogFile
     -#       Log file name for LogType 'file' parameter.
     +#       Log file name for LogType 'file' parameter.
      #
      # Mandatory: no
      # Default:
      # LogFile=

     -LogFile=/tmp/zabbix_agentd.log
     +LogFile=/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.log

      ### Option: LogFileSize
     -#       Maximum size of log file in MB.
     -#       0 - disable automatic log rotation.
     +#       Maximum size of log file in MB.
     +#       0 - disable automatic log rotation.
      #
      # Mandatory: no
      # Range: 0-1024
      # Default:
     -# LogFileSize=1
     +#LogFileSize=1

      ### Option: DebugLevel
     -#       Specifies debug level:
     -#       0 - basic information about starting and stopping of Zabbix processes
     -#       1 - critical information
     -#       2 - error information
     -#       3 - warnings
     -#       4 - for debugging (produces lots of information)
     -#       5 - extended debugging (produces even more information)
     +#       Specifies debug level:
     +#       0 - basic information about starting and stopping of Zabbix processes
     +#       1 - critical information
     +#       2 - error information
     +#       3 - warnings
     +#       4 - for debugging (produces lots of information)
     +#       5 - extended debugging (produces even more information)
      #
      # Mandatory: no
      # Range: 0-5
      # Default:
     -# DebugLevel=3
     +# DebugLevel=4

      ### Option: SourceIP
     -#       Source IP address for outgoing connections.
     +#       Source IP address for outgoing connections.
      #
      # Mandatory: no
      # Default:
      # SourceIP=

      ### Option: EnableRemoteCommands
     -#       Whether remote commands from Zabbix server are allowed.
     -#       0 - not allowed
     -#       1 - allowed
     +#       Whether remote commands from Zabbix server are allowed.
     +#       0 - not allowed
     +#       1 - allowed
      #
      # Mandatory: no
      # Default:
      # EnableRemoteCommands=0

      ### Option: LogRemoteCommands
     -#       Enable logging of executed shell commands as warnings.
     -#       0 - disabled
     -#       1 - enabled
     +#       Enable logging of executed shell commands as warnings.
     +#       0 - disabled
     +#       1 - enabled
      #
      # Mandatory: no
      # Default:
     @@ -80,35 +81,35 @@
      ##### Passive checks related

      ### Option: Server
     -#       List of comma delimited IP addresses (or hostnames) of Zabbix servers.
     -#       Incoming connections will be accepted only from the hosts listed here.
     -#       If IPv6 support is enabled then '127.0.0.1', '::127.0.0.1', '::ffff:127.0.0.1' are treated equally.
     +#       List of comma delimited IP addresses (or hostnames) of Zabbix servers.
     +#       Incoming connections will be accepted only from the hosts listed here.
     +#       If IPv6 support is enabled then '127.0.0.1', '::127.0.0.1', '::ffff:127.0.0.1' are treated equally.
      #
      # Mandatory: no
      # Default:
      # Server=

     -Server=127.0.0.1
     +Server=XXX.XXX.XXX.XX

      ### Option: ListenPort
     -#       Agent will listen on this port for connections from the server.
     +#       Agent will listen on this port for connections from the server.
      #
      # Mandatory: no
      # Range: 1024-32767
      # Default:
     -# ListenPort=10050
     + ListenPort=10050

      ### Option: ListenIP
     -#       List of comma delimited IP addresses that the agent should listen on.
     -#       First IP address is sent to Zabbix server if connecting to it to retrieve list of active checks.
     +#       List of comma delimited IP addresses that the agent should listen on.
     +#       First IP address is sent to Zabbix server if connecting to it to retrieve list of active checks.
      #
      # Mandatory: no
      # Default:
      # ListenIP=0.0.0.0

      ### Option: StartAgents
     -#       Number of pre-forked instances of zabbix_agentd that process passive checks.
     -#       If set to 0, disables passive checks and the agent will not listen on any TCP port.
     +#       Number of pre-forked instances of zabbix_agentd that process passive checks.
     +#       If set to 0, disables passive checks and the agent will not listen on any TCP port.
      #
      # Mandatory: no
      # Range: 0-100
     @@ -118,43 +119,43 @@
      ##### Active checks related

      ### Option: ServerActive
     -#       List of comma delimited IP:port (or hostname:port) pairs of Zabbix servers for active checks.
     -#       If port is not specified, default port is used.
     -#       IPv6 addresses must be enclosed in square brackets if port for that host is specified.
     -#       If port is not specified, square brackets for IPv6 addresses are optional.
     -#       If this parameter is not specified, active checks are disabled.
     -#       Example: ServerActive=127.0.0.1:20051,zabbix.domain,[::1]:30051,::1,[12fc::1]
     +#       List of comma delimited IP:port (or hostname:port) pairs of Zabbix servers for active checks.
     +#       If port is not specified, default port is used.
     +#       IPv6 addresses must be enclosed in square brackets if port for that host is specified.
     +#       If port is not specified, square brackets for IPv6 addresses are optional.
     +#       If this parameter is not specified, active checks are disabled.
     +#       Example: ServerActive=127.0.0.1:20051,zabbix.domain,[::1]:30051,::1,[12fc::1]
      #
      # Mandatory: no
      # Default:
      # ServerActive=

     -ServerActive=127.0.0.1
     +#ServerActive=127.0.0.1

      ### Option: Hostname
     -#       Unique, case sensitive hostname.
     -#       Required for active checks and must match hostname as configured on the server.
     -#       Value is acquired from HostnameItem if undefined.
     +#       Unique, case sensitive hostname.
     +#       Required for active checks and must match hostname as configured on the server.
     +#       Value is acquired from HostnameItem if undefined.
      #
      # Mandatory: no
      # Default:
      # Hostname=

     -Hostname=Zabbix server
     +#Hostname=system.hostname

      ### Option: HostnameItem
     -#       Item used for generating Hostname if it is undefined. Ignored if Hostname is defined.
     -#       Does not support UserParameters or aliases.
     +#       Item used for generating Hostname if it is undefined. Ignored if Hostname is defined.
     +#       Does not support UserParameters or aliases.
      #
      # Mandatory: no
      # Default:
      # HostnameItem=system.hostname

      ### Option: HostMetadata
     -#       Optional parameter that defines host metadata.
     -#       Host metadata is used at host auto-registration process.
     -#       An agent will issue an error and not start if the value is over limit of 255 characters.
     -#       If not defined, value will be acquired from HostMetadataItem.
     +#       Optional parameter that defines host metadata.
     +#       Host metadata is used at host auto-registration process.
     +#       An agent will issue an error and not start if the value is over limit of 255 characters.
     +#       If not defined, value will be acquired from HostMetadataItem.
      #
      # Mandatory: no
      # Range: 0-255 characters
     @@ -162,18 +163,18 @@
      # HostMetadata=

              +#       Host metadata is used at host auto-registration process.
             +#       the value returned by specified item is over limit of 255 characters.
     +#       This option is only used when HostMetadata is not defined.
      #
      # Mandatory: no
      # Default:
      # HostMetadataItem=

      ### Option: RefreshActiveChecks
    +#       How often list of active checks is refreshed, in seconds.
      #
      # Mandatory: no
      # Range: 60-3600
     @@ -181,7 +182,7 @@
      # RefreshActiveChecks=120

      ### Option: BufferSend
     -#       Do not keep data longer than N seconds in buffer.
     +#       Do not keep data longer than N seconds in buffer.
      #
      # Mandatory: no
      # Range: 1-3600
     @@ -189,8 +190,8 @@
      # BufferSend=5

      ### Option: BufferSize
     -#       Maximum number of values in a memory buffer. The agent will send
     -#       all collected data to Zabbix Server or Proxy if the buffer is full.
     +#       Maximum number of values in a memory buffer. The agent will send
     +#       all collected data to Zabbix Server or Proxy if the buffer is full.
      #
      # Mandatory: no
      # Range: 2-65535
     @@ -198,10 +199,10 @@
      # BufferSize=100

      ### Option: MaxLinesPerSecond
     -#       Maximum number of new lines the agent will send per second to Zabbix Server
     -#       or Proxy processing 'log' and 'logrt' active checks.
     -#       The provided value will be overridden by the parameter 'maxlines',
     -#       provided in 'log' or 'logrt' item keys.
     +#       Maximum number of new lines the agent will send per second to Zabbix Server
     +#       or Proxy processing 'log' and 'logrt' active checks.
     +#       The provided value will be overridden by the parameter 'maxlines',
     +#       provided in 'log' or 'logrt' item keys.
      #
      # Mandatory: no
      # Range: 1-1000
     @@ -211,20 +212,20 @@
      ############ ADVANCED PARAMETERS #################

      ### Option: Alias
     -#       Sets an alias for an item key. It can be used to substitute long and complex item key with a smaller and simpler one.
     -#       Multiple Alias parameters may be present. Multiple parameters with the same Alias key are not allowed.
     -#       Different Alias keys may reference the same item key.
     -#       For example, to retrieve the ID of user 'zabbix':
     -#       Alias=zabbix.userid:vfs.file.regexp[/etc/passwd,^zabbix:.:([0-9]+),,,,\1]
     -#       Now shorthand key zabbix.userid may be used to retrieve data.
     -#       Aliases can be used in HostMetadataItem but not in HostnameItem parameters.
     +#       Sets an alias for an item key. It can be used to substitute long and complex item key with a smaller and simpler one.
     +#       Multiple Alias parameters may be present. Multiple parameters with the same Alias key are not allowed.
     +#       Different Alias keys may reference the same item key.
     +#       For example, to retrieve the ID of user 'zabbix':
     +#       Alias=zabbix.userid:vfs.file.regexp[/etc/passwd,^zabbix:.:([0-9]+),,,,\1]
     +#       Now shorthand key zabbix.userid may be used to retrieve data.
     +#       Aliases can be used in HostMetadataItem but not in HostnameItem parameters.
      #
      # Mandatory: no
      # Range:
      # Default:

      ### Option: Timeout
     +#       Spend no more than Timeout seconds on processing
      #
      # Mandatory: no
      # Range: 1-30
     @@ -232,45 +233,45 @@
      # Timeout=3

      ### Option: AllowRoot
     -#       will try to switch to the user specified by the User configuration option instead.
     -#       Has no effect if started under a regular user.
     -#       0 - do not allow
     -#       1 - allow
     +#       Allow the agent to run as 'root'. If disabled and the agent is started by 'root', the agent
     +#       will try to switch to the user specified by the User configuration option instead.
     +#       Has no effect if started under a regular user.
     +#       0 - do not allow
     +#       1 - allow
      # Mandatory: no
      # Default:
     -# AllowRoot=0
     + AllowRoot=1
      ### Option: User
      # Mandatory: no
      # Default:
      # User=zabbix
     ### Option: Include
     -#       You may include individual files or all files in a directory in the configuration file.
     -#       Installing Zabbix will create include directory in /usr/local/etc, unless modified during the compile time.
     +#       You may include individual files or all files in a directory in the configuration file.
     +#       Installing Zabbix will create include directory in /usr/local/etc, unless modified during the compile time.
      #
      # Mandatory: no
      # Default:
      # Include=

      # Include=/usr/local/etc/zabbix_agentd.userparams.conf
     -# Include=/usr/local/etc/zabbix_agentd.conf.d/
     + Include=/usr/local/etc/zabbix_agentd.conf.d/
      # Include=/usr/local/etc/zabbix_agentd.conf.d/*.conf

      ####### USER-DEFINED MONITORED PARAMETERS #######

      ### Option: UnsafeUserParameters
     -#       Allow all characters to be passed in arguments to user-defined parameters.
     -#       The following characters are not allowed:
     -#       \ ' " ` * ? [ ] { } ~ $ ! & ; ( ) < > | # @
     -#       Additionally, newline characters are not allowed.
     -#       0 - do not allow
     -#       1 - allow
     +#       Allow all characters to be passed in arguments to user-defined parameters.
     +#       The following characters are not allowed:
     +#       \ ' " ` * ? [ ] { } ~ $ ! & ; ( ) < > | # @
     +#       Additionally, newline characters are not allowed.
     +#       0 - do not allow
     +#       1 - allow
      #
      # Mandatory: no
      # Range: 0-1
     @@ -278,9 +279,9 @@
      # UnsafeUserParameters=0

      ### Option: UserParameter
     -#       User-defined parameter to monitor. There can be several user-defined parameters.
     -#       Format: UserParameter=<key>,<shell command>
     -#       See 'zabbix_agentd' directory for examples.
     +#       User-defined parameter to monitor. There can be several user-defined parameters.
     +#       Format: UserParameter=<key>,<shell command>
     +#       See 'zabbix_agentd' directory for examples.
      #
      # Mandatory: no
      # Default:
     @@ -289,18 +290,18 @@
      ####### LOADABLE MODULES #######

      ### Option: LoadModulePath
     -#       Full path to location of agent modules.
     -#       Default depends on compilation options.
     +#       Full path to location of agent modules.
     +#       Default depends on compilation options.
      #
      # Mandatory: no
      # Default:
      # LoadModulePath=${libdir}/modules

      ### Option: LoadModule
     -#       Module to load at agent startup. Modules are used to extend functionality of the agent.
     -#       Format: LoadModule=<module.so>
     -#       The modules must be located in directory specified by LoadModulePath.
     -#       It is allowed to include multiple LoadModule parameters.
     +#       Module to load at agent startup. Modules are used to extend functionality of the agent.
     +#       Format: LoadModule=<module.so>
     +#       The modules must be located in directory specified by LoadModulePath.
     +#       It is allowed to include multiple LoadModule parameters.
      #
      # Mandatory: no
      # Default:
     @@ -309,37 +310,37 @@
      ####### TLS-RELATED PARAMETERS #######

      ### Option: TLSConnect
     -#       How the agent should connect to server or proxy. Used for active checks.
     -#       Only one value can be specified:
     -#               unencrypted - connect without encryption
     -#               psk         - connect using TLS and a pre-shared key
     -#               cert        - connect using TLS and a certificate
     +#       How the agent should connect to server or proxy. Used for active checks.
     +#       Only one value can be specified:
     +#               unencrypted - connect without encryption
     +#               psk         - connect using TLS and a pre-shared key
     +#               cert        - connect using TLS and a certificate
      #
      # Mandatory: yes, if TLS certificate or PSK parameters are defined (even for 'unencrypted' connection)
      # Default:
      # TLSConnect=unencrypted

      ### Option: TLSAccept
     -#       What incoming connections to accept.
     -#       Multiple values can be specified, separated by comma:
     -#               unencrypted - accept connections without encryption
     -#               psk         - accept connections secured with TLS and a pre-shared key
     -#               cert        - accept connections secured with TLS and a certificate
     +#       What incoming connections to accept.
     +#       Multiple values can be specified, separated by comma:
     +#               unencrypted - accept connections without encryption
     +#               psk         - accept connections secured with TLS and a pre-shared key
     +#               cert        - accept connections secured with TLS and a certificate
      #
      # Mandatory: yes, if TLS certificate or PSK parameters are defined (even for 'unencrypted' connection)
      # Default:
      # TLSAccept=unencrypted

      ### Option: TLSCAFile
     -#       Full pathname of a file containing the top-level CA(s) certificates for
     -#       peer certificate verification.
     +#       Full pathname of a file containing the top-level CA(s) certificates for
     +#       peer certificate verification.
      #
      # Mandatory: no
      # Default:
      # TLSCAFile=

      ### Option: TLSCRLFile
     -#       Full pathname of a file containing revoked certificates.
     +#       Full pathname of a file containing revoked certificates.
      #
      # Mandatory: no
      # Default:
     @@ -360,30 +361,31 @@
      # TLSServerCertSubject=

      ### Option: TLSCertFile
     -#       Full pathname of a file containing the agent certificate or certificate chain.
     +#       Full pathname of a file containing the agent certificate or certificate chain.
      #
      # Mandatory: no
      # Default:
      # TLSCertFile=

      ### Option: TLSKeyFile
     -#       Full pathname of a file containing the agent private key.
     +#       Full pathname of a file containing the agent private key.
      #
      # Mandatory: no
      # Default:
      # TLSKeyFile=

      ### Option: TLSPSKIdentity
     -#       Unique, case sensitive string used to identify the pre-shared key.
     +#       Unique, case sensitive string used to identify the pre-shared key.
      #
      # Mandatory: no
      # Default:
      # TLSPSKIdentity=

      ### Option: TLSPSKFile
     -#       Full pathname of a file containing the pre-shared key.
     +#       Full pathname of a file containing the pre-shared key.
      #
      # Mandatory: no
      # Default:
      # TLSPSKFile=
     +
     - change mode from '0644' to '0755'
     - change owner from 'root' to 'zabbix'
     - change group from 'root' to 'zabbix'
   * template[/etc/init.d/zabbix-agent] action create
     - create new file /etc/init.d/zabbix-agent
     - change mode from '' to '0755'
     - change owner from '' to 'root'
     - change group from '' to 'root'
   * bash[agent] action run
     - execute "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20170125-2651-jd9ecj"

 Running handlers:
 Running handlers complete
 Chef Client finished, 6/7 resources updated in 01 minutes 10 seconds
```

I'm trying to Install Zabbix Agent on AML through chef, the Agent is starting but it's also stopping during the chef run. I'm able to start the agent successfully by logging into the Amazon machine but not through chef. Logfile is given above.I removed the init.d script from the chef logs because of character constraint. Any suggestions ?

Comment: What about the Chef logs?

Comment: The chef recipe is getting executed successfully with out any errors.

Comment: Yes but what's in the log

Comment: Increase zabbix agent log level and you may see more details in the agent log file,

Comment: I changed the log level to 4 in in the zabbix config file but that didn't give much info too.

Comment: @coderanger I have added the chef logs to the post and had to remove the template of init.d while posting it here because of the character constraint.
Thanks!

Comment: @JanGaraj I have added the zabbix log's with debug level 4. Thanks!

Comment: You are changing pid path. Is there any pid dependency in startup script? It looks like init system is killing zabbix.

Comment: I tried with the default pid path and it was the same too. There is no pid dependency in startup script. I was able to start the zabbix agent normally by logging in to the server but only through chef run it's getting killed.

Comment: @JanGaraj I see that during the chef run the zabbix_agent.log is getting created but not the zabbix_agent.pid, that might be the issue.

Comment: Chef does not appear to be touching the service at all, unless you're doing something manually in that `bash` resource, in which case you should check your code.

Comment: My script was creating an AMI of EC2-Instance which was stopping the zabbix-agent. Thanks for your time :) @coderanger

Comment: Your question is not about programming, it is about Linux. I suggest to ask this question on https://unix.stackexchange.com, or on https://serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0):

My script was creating a base AMI of the EC2-Instance which was making the zabbix agent to stop. I was able to add zabbix-agent to chkconfig and resolve the issue.

Thanks!